# Difference between SOAP & SMTP protocol

Tags: soap, smtp, protocols

What is the difference between SOAP ans SMTP protocol?
What is relation between them?

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms :
SOAP (simple object access protocol) is an application communication protocol used for sending and receiving messages based on xml.

And SMTP (simple mail transfer protocol) is a protocol for sending and recieving email messages over internet.